# insert image of BLOB format+iphone

Tags: iphone, image, store

I have one sqlite database which has one table in which I store the image id and image which datatype is BLOB I don't know how to insert image through database side any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: thanks i solved that using reading this http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/02/sqlite-tutorial-saving-images-in.html which is very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while saving other data in database with that you can save image too using sqlite3_bind_blob.

Answer (score 0):

YEs friend you can insert image using NSData type...